# Is there any library for sinhalese language in flutter localization?

Tags: flutter, localization

I’m developing a mobile application using flutter to be used in my country. i have to use Sinhalese language(SriLankan) font in the mobile UIs. I have searched in the Flutter Community and i was unable to find a proper solution.I want to know whether there is a flutter_localization library that can be used in my application?

Comment: currently there is no any class available in flutter_localization library in my language (Sinhala) like yo MaterialLocalizationAr...so how can i get a solution

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use this Medium [post](https://medium.com/saugo360/managing-locale-in-flutter-7693a9d4d6ac) as a guide. Although it implements Arabic and English as demonstration it will be beneficial to you since one of them is left-to-right and the other is right-to-left.

Comment: currently there is no any class available in flutter_localization library in my language like your MaterialLocalizationAr (arabic)..so i want to that solution

Comment: I doubt you'll find anyone soon. I advise you to use the above methodology I mentioned since it doesn't depend on any underlying support, you'll just support the keywords and translations as keys in a map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this article to integrate localisation in app. 
[Article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/internationalization---make-an-flutter-application-multi-lingual/) it's really quick to integrate in app.

However if your language isn't supported by flutter_localizations library even though you can provide support using above class as mentioned on article.

here is snap

[image]

Comment: my language is Sinhala (Srilankan).is it not support in flutter_localizations library?..how can i use  below that in my language supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
    const Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic
    // ... other locales the app supports
  ],

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement localization in App. I found a simple example for the same [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/03/flutter-localization-or-multi-language-example.html).